# Replace all URL's for my WordPress site using a different domain name?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns

The domain names used are only examples, so if you could use those example names in your answer that would be great. I'm having a very hard time wording exactly what I'm trying to do and because of that can't find the answer via searching, so I'm posting it as this analogy:

---

I work for a company that makes WordPress sites. We'll call that company SuperMedia, and their main website is supermedia.com. SuperMedia wants to host their clients' sites on their own server via subfolders. So in this case, we've created a client's WordPress site in the directory http://supermedia.com/greatclient/

The issue is that our client has a domain name, friendlyclient.com, and we need to link this domain name to their site which we are hosting on our server, but we don't want the urls to show "supermedia" at all.

---

So in simplest terms, right now all of our page urls look like this:

http://supermedia.com/greatclient/about

http://supermedia.com/greatclient/our-services

http://supermedia.com/greatclient/gallery

(etc...)

But we want them all to say:

http://friendlyclient.com/about

http://friendlyclient.com/our-services

http://friendlyclient.com/gallery

(etc...)

but still display the information on http://supermedia.com/greatclient/about, http://supermedia.com/greatclient/our-services, http://supermedia.com/greatclient/gallery, etc. respectively.

---

Is there a simple, fairly fast way to do this for all the pages we've created, either using .htaccess or some kind of plugin? I don't have a lot of back-end programming/database knowledge, so if it involves advanced programming, could you lay-out some steps on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, you can use mod_rewrite to do the rewriting. Try adding this to your .htaccess file(In the friendlyclient.com root folder)

```
# Match the host    
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.com$ [NC]

# proxy the entire request to the /host/ and path    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.supermedia.com/%1/$1  [L,P]
```

This will make it so requesting http://friendly.com/about will serve http://www.supermedia.com/friendlyclient/about and dont forget to rename ur folder, from **greatclient** to **friedlyclient**

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately. I just get "Not Found" pages. I'm hearing from other sources now that I need to set up Multisite to do this properly? Was tring to avoid doing that but if there's no alternative I'll just have to buckle down and do it that way.